# How to add custom libraries into C++ builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, libraries

I am new to C++ builder. I'm wonder how exactly do I add custom libraries to C++ builder? I understand they have something called "get it package manager", the libraries I need aren't in it.

I'm wondering is there a way I can simply integrate like vcpkg with C++ builder? Because I already have all my libraries with vcpkg, so a way to some how use C++ builder with vcpkg would be amazing. What do you guys do to add libraries?

Also how do use like for example windows.h in my project or something like OpenMP (OMP)? I'm having a tough time even finding the place in options where I add the includes for libraries? I'm used to visual studio lol, your help is appreciated!

Comment: What library do you want? What package manager that you're using now lacks it?

Comment: I'm just confused how adding libraries works in RAD C++ builder. like for visual studio for example, i just integrate vcpkg and thats, that. But I'm lost with C++ builder. I just want to know how exactly I add libraries bud. Also if its possible to integrate vcpkg with RAD C++ builder?

Comment: I haven't tried, but can't you use the vcpkg-installed libraries directly from C++Builder? You'd have to add the library path to the C++Builder project I guess, but wouldn't that work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ted! Do you possibly know how I add the library path in C++ builder? Like for example in visual studio, you right click the solution, properties, go into C/C++ tab and you simply add under "additional includes directories" the same for the linker. But how does it work for C++ builder? I'm having a tough time finding anything similar inside of it.

Comment: Use `@username` when replying to comments, otherwise people won't get notifications. Why must you use C++ builder? And again, what package manager did you use with C++ builder? Does it have a built-in one? What library do you want installed?

Comment: @Merkdon did you even look at C++Builder's [project options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Options_Dialog_Box) yet? The C++ section has path settings for include files and linker libs. Also see [Setting Project Options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Project_Options)